# QT SQL Create table with placeholder as name

Tags: c++, sql, qt-creator, placeholder, qtsql

I want to create `Tables` which use the `actual year as name`.
All I tried ended up returning an empty file.

First I tried to convert the variable to `hex`:

```
query.prepare("CREATE TABLE " + year.toUtf8().toHex() +
              "(buy_date DATE, "
               "category VARCHAR(28), "
               "price FLOAT, "
               "comment TINYTEXT)");
```

After I tried it with `QString` and `arguments`:

```
query.prepare(QString("CREATE TABLE %1 "
              "(buy_date DATE, "
               "category VARCHAR(28), "
               "price FLOAT, "
               "comment TINYTEXT)").arg(year));
```

And the last try was using `Value binding`:

```
query.prepare("CREATE TABLE :year "
              "(buy_date DATE, "
               "category VARCHAR(28), "
               "price FLOAT, "
               "comment TINYTEXT)");

query.bindValue(":year", year);
```

All failed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

It does work as it should.
Can't use numbers as Table name:

```
query.prepare("CREATE TABLE '" + year + "' "
              "(buy_date DATE, "
               "category VARCHAR(28), "
               "price FLOAT, "
               "comment TINYTEXT)");
```

Or:

```
query.prepare(QString("CREATE TABLE %1 "
              "(buy_date DATE, "
               "category VARCHAR(28), "
               "price FLOAT, "
               "comment TINYTEXT)").arg("'" + year + "'"));
```

But I would still like to know why it doesn't work with `query.bindValue`?